# Google spreadsheet obscure fields with passwords

Tags: google-sheets, passwords

I would like to create a spreadsheet to manage my domain information in one place. I was thinking of creating rules that made dates red when registration and contracts were expiring and whatnot.

I was then thinking that I might want to keep the passwords in the same location. Besides whether or not I should trust my passwords to a Google spreadsheets the one thing I would like is to obscure them.

Is there a script or gadget I can use to show an asterisk until highlighted or is there a way to format them so they aren't just there on the page?

Comment: Set the text and background colors the same?

Answer (score 4):

You could set the text color and background color to black, which should be good enough if all you are worried about is people looking over your shoulder.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing you do can really secure the passwords stored in this way properly. It would require cryptographic algorithms which you cannot easily introduce into a third-party Web service in the way you want.

You could limit the contest of the document to just usernames and server addresses. And then instruct your fellow administrators (don’t keep these instructions in the document, obviously) to run the addresses, username, and a single secure agreed upon Project master password through something like [PwdHash.](https://www.pwdhash.com/) This should be much more secure than storing the passwords in a plain-text document.